# Doctrine: how to tell if an object is part of a collection

Tags: doctrine-orm

Short question. If `r` has a property `colors` and I want to see if a given `$color` is set on `r`, how do I build that? I tried:

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')->where('?1 IN r.colors')->setParameter(1,$color);
```

and

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')->where('r.colors = ?1')->setParameter(1,$color);
```

but neither work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')->join('r.colors', 'c', 'WITH', 'c = ?2')->where('r.device = ?1')->setParameters([1=>$device, 2=>$color]);
```

does it.